# where clause to retrieve case record which are older than 12 months and 1 day in soql

Tags: soql

Please help me in writing where clause to retrieve case record which are older than 12 months and 1 day SOQL

Comment: You could have a look at the documentation [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm), give it a try and let us know where you are stuck.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can try using something from this Salesforce link here. [SOQL date query filters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm).

```
Select Id from Object where Date = LAST_N_DAYS:366
```

Answer (score 4):

+1 to Raj's answer if you don't mind being a day out around leap years:

```
 ... where CreatedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:366
```

If you did need to address leap years:

```
 Date d = Date.today().addYears(-1).addDays(-1);

 ... where DAY_ONLY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate)) < :d
```

See my colleague's [Gotcha: convertTimezone() must be used in SOQL Date functions dealing with Datetime](https://force746.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/gotcha-converttimezone-must-be-used-in-soql-date-functions-dealing-with-datetime/) post for an explanation of the need for `convertTimezone`.